# Python, iOS - Can I write the model of my app in python

Tags: python, objective-c, ios

I want to write a computer algebra system for iOS (just for fun), and I think it would be better if the kernel code was written in Python. So I want a way to:

Call Python code from Objective-C on iOS,
Access the properties and methods of Python objects from Objective-C:

I am going to do all the GUI (View) code in Objective-C, I won't need to call Cocoa from Python.

Comment: http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: PyObjC isn't well supported on iOS unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1) Use kivy (http://kivy.org/#home), its compatible with iOS but you'll have to write the UI in python (I haven't tried to do otherwise so there might be a way).

2) Use something like PyObjC (http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/). You can write your logic in normal python modules and then use from objective-C UI code.